handlebars lightncandy php libary nested each statements lose access to variables established in higher loop
Consider the following minimal example of handlebars Javascript.
{{#each arr as | topLevel topIndex |}}
    {{topLevel.value}}
     {{#each topLevel.children as | secondLevel secondIndex |}}
            ---- {{topLevel.value}}, {{secondLevel.value}}
           {{#each secondLevel.children as | thirdLevel thirdIndex |}}
                  -------- {{topLevel.value}}, {{secondLevel.value}}, {{thirdLevel.value}}
           {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}

It works happily and renders the following:
ABC
        ---- ABC, DEF
              -------- ABC, DEF, GHI
              -------- ABC, DEF, JKL
        ---- ABC, MNO
              -------- ABC, MNO, PQR
              -------- ABC, MNO, STU
XYZ
        ---- XYZ, LMN
              -------- XYZ, LMN, OPQ
              -------- XYZ, LMN, RST
        ---- XYZ, UVW
              -------- XYZ, UVW, XYZ
              -------- XYZ, UVW, ABC

Notice how in each nested "each" block I can access variable names established within the | | of prior each blocks. I do not need to include anything special such as ../ in order to access them.
My question is how can I achieve completely identical results in PHP's Lightncandy library (the PHP implementation of handlebars) Currently with the following flags...
LightnCandy::FLAG_ERROR_LOG | LightnCandy::FLAG_STANDALONEPHP | LightnCandy::FLAG_HANDLEBARSJS | LightnCandy::FLAG_ADVARNAME | LightnCandy::FLAG_SPVARS | LightnCandy::FLAG_PARENT | LightnCandy::FLAG_JSTRUE | LightnCandy::FLAG_JSOBJECT,  

... each nested else statement loses access to previous alias's and index variables set in higher-level loops.
I really need this to work so I am hoping there is a flag or configuration that can make lightncandy behave like the JS implementation.

Block parameters are not supported and I see you've opened an issue with LightnCandy here https://github.com/zordius/lightncandy/issues/371, so can you provide the modified MRE of the PHP counterpart, please? Does the counterpart work in handlebars.js?
